# Barista Classes

Tags: coffee-shop

There are several courses available for aspiring baristas to take.  I am interested in opening a farmer's market coffee stand, I have zero Barista experience, however some of these courses are very pricey but are backed by organizations such as the Specialty Coffee Association of America.  I have come across other options at local community colleges under the Barista I and II guise.  At the surface, these two classes do not look that much different, is there anything specifically that I should look for when enrolling in a course like this

From SCAA, Barista I

`Learn the basics of espresso preparation, milk, and drink building in the Level 1 Barista Pathway. With access to the best tools, coffees, and industry leaders, Level 1 Barista students receive expertly lead training and a comprehensive introduction to the espresso craft.`

From a local community college, extension program

`Learn about coffee, how to prepare and serve espresso and espresso based drinks. Program will show how to use espresso/cappuccino machine at a commercial level, and will make you confident around coffee and equipment. Completion of Barista program will include a Basic Barista Certification, which can be used for employment referral.
Class will be instructed by a Specialty Coffee Consultant, who has more than 15 years of experience in Italian espresso, espresso equipment (at an engineering level)and barista training in over 80 restaurants and coffee shops.`

Comment: Hi Geoffery! 

Your question is a little ambiguous and might be worded better. Are you interested in what to look for in a barista class/course or whether or not one certified by a professional organization is better than similar options?

Answer (score 3):

The SCAA-certified classes will be of more benefit to you if you're looking for employment at a coffee shop as a barista, roaster, etc.

Given that you're interested in learning the fundamentals of coffee in order to open a farmers market coffee stand, I would say go with the cheaper option. Both will teach you what it is you seek, but only one will set you back thousands of dollars gaining certifications.

*Note:* The SCAA has strict guidelines that some coffee shops simply cannot meet for reasons of cost or another. From the [SCAA's education website](http://scaaeducation.org):

> All Campus locations have successfully completed the **SCAA Certified Teaching Laboratory program**, demonstrating a calibrated teaching environment to teach within **SCAA standards and protocols**.
>
> Campuses also are **required to employ only SCAA Certified Specialized Instructors** for class offerings, ensuring the highest quality of instruction regardless of which Campus a student attends.

Basically, an excellent instructor with all the best equipment who can't afford to take the SCAA classes or meet the space requirements for a teaching space can't teach said classes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SCAA/SCAE and similar bodies offer *somehow worldwide* recognized certificates. Local courses may not have such reputation. To learn the basics for yourself, they may both work for you.